# ParentView attributes set to nil after adding/removing a ViewController as a subview Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController called VCA that will create a popUp ViewController called VCB. VCB allows the user to select some information and then pass it back to VCA. The problem is that when i pass the values in VCB back to VCA, all of VCA attributes are now nil or set to their type defaults
Here is the code that creates VCB in VCA

```
let VCB = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)    
VCB.showInView(self.view)
VCB.delegate = ViewControllerA()
```

ViewControllerB

```
func showInView(aView: UIView!)
{
    view.center = aView.center
    aView.addSubview(self.view)
}
```

Then I close VCB

```
@IBAction func recordButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate.someMethod(someValue: someType, ...)
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

But when someMethod(...) is called the attributes in VCA are set to nil and I get a

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any help or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the delegate of VCB like so:

```
vcb.delegate = ViewControllerA()
```

that is instantiating a new instance of VCA.

You presumably meant to set the delegate of VCB to an existing instance of VCA. For example, if done from within VBA's instance method, you'd simply do:

```
vcb.delegate = self
```

--

BTW, when adding VCB's view into your view hierarchy, you really should do the containment calls `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`:

```
let vcb = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
addChildViewController(vcb)
vcb.showInView(self.view)
vcb.delegate = self
vcb.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Likewise, when you remove it, call `willMoveToParentViewController` and `removeFromParentViewController`:

```
@IBAction func recordButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.someMethod(someValue: someType, ...)

    willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
    removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

You always want to keep your view controller hierarchy in sync with your view hierarchy. See the *Implementing a Container View Controller* section of the [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW86).